# Repeating a table row after form submission in PHP

Tags: php

I need to repeat the row echod out, at the moment it displays the row when the form is submitted but as soon as I submit it again it overwrites my previous row, would it be possible to add a row?

I used a session as I would like to do this without a database

I will also need to calculate all the numbers in the total cost column.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="edit-Type" edit="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>JSFiddle</title>

<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/embed/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script src="/js/embed/embed.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/css/embed/embed-light.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" />

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
</style>

</head>
<body>


<?php 

if(isset($_POST['add_ingredient'])) {

$_SESSION['ingredient'] = $_POST['ingredient'];
$_SESSION['num1'] = $_POST['num1'];
$_SESSION['num2'] = $_POST['num2'];
$_SESSION['num3'] = $_POST['num3'];

}


if(isset($_POST['selling_price_input'])) {

$_SESSION['selling_price'] = $_POST['selling_price'];
}      


?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    

<div class="form-group">
<label>Ingredient</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ingredient">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Price</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="num1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Qty Grams/Item</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="num2">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Recipe Qty Grams/Item</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="num3">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add_ingredient" value="Add Ingredient">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Selling Price</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="selling_price">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="selling_price_input" value="Update">
</div>
</form>


<!-----------------------------------------------------DISPLAYING------------->   

<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Ingredients</th>
<th>Item Price</th>
<th>Item Qty Grams/Unit</th>
<th>Recipe Qty Grams/Unit</th>
<th>Total Cost</th>

</tr>

</thead>
<tbody>


<?php

//calculation variables
$num1 = $_SESSION['num1'];
$num2 = $_SESSION['num2'];
$num3 = $_SESSION['num3'];
$ingredient = $_SESSION['ingredient'];
$selling_price = $_SESSION['selling_price'];
//$sellnum = $_GET['sellnum'];
$cost = $num1 / $num2 * $num3;
$profit =  $selling_price - $cost ;
$profper =  $profit / $selling_price * 100;    


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$ingredient</td>";
echo "<td>$num1</td>";

echo "<td>$num2</td>";
echo "<td>$num3</td>";
echo "<td>$cost</td>";
echo "</tr>";

?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Total Cost of Recipe</td>
<?php  echo "<td>$cost</td>"; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Selling price of each baked item</td>
<?php echo "<td>$selling_price</td>"; ?>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Profit per item</td>
<?php  echo "<td colspan='2'>$profit</td>"; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Profit Percentage</td>
<?php  echo "<td colspan='2'>$profper%</td>"; ?>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="6">Note: Your profit should never be more than 30% of the cost of you your product</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with answering your question is that, how do I put it, no answer can be complete. There will always be other questions. Just keep in mind that this answer is only meant to give you a hint, it doesn't solve all problems. It is only an answer to the question: *"... would it be possible to add a row?"*

The answer is, of course: *"Yes!"*

What you currently do, after a form submit, is overwrite the information that is present in the session:

```
$_SESSION['ingredient'] = $_POST['ingredient'];
$_SESSION['num1'] = $_POST['num1'];
$_SESSION['num2'] = $_POST['num2'];
$_SESSION['num3'] = $_POST['num3'];
```

That's clearly not what you want. A solution is to have an array with ingredients and store that in the session, like this:

```
$_SESSION['ingredients'][] = ['ingredient' => $_POST['ingredient'],
                              'num1'       => $_POST['num1'],
                              'num2'       => $_POST['num2'],
                              'num3'       => $_POST['num3']];
```

I'm totally not in favour of using `num1`, `num2`, `num3`, but I'll stick to answering the question.

Now when you want to render your table you have to loop through the array:

```
// first start the table here

foreach ($_SESSION['ingredients'] as $ingredient) {
    $ingredient = $ingredient['ingredient'];
    $num1       = $ingredient['num1'];
    $num2       = $ingredient['num2'];
    $num3       = $ingredient['num3'];

    // render one row of the table here

}

// finally end the table here
```

I haven't included the price intentionally, but it is just another field.

As said before: This answer will not solve all the problems, it's only a hint.

Comment: thanks so much! very new to php will give the above a try, will post if successful

Comment: seems like it still overrides the previous row

Comment: I cannot see your current code, so I can't help you. See the manual for [array_push()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). It explains how `$array[] = $var;` is equal to `array_push($array, $var)`, and what it does. In your case you're doing: `array_push($_SESSION['ingredients'], $newRow)` where `$newRow` is the data contained in the new row.

Comment: I can't work with that, I need to see the whole code. However, I need to leave now, so I can't comment anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="edit-Type" edit="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>JSFiddle</title>

<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/embed/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script src="/js/embed/embed.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/css/embed/embed-light.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" />

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
</style>

</head>
<body>


<?php 

if(isset($_POST['add_ingredient'])) {

$_SESSION['ingredients'][] = ['ingredient' => $_POST['ingredient'],
                              'num1'       => $_POST['num1'],
                              'num2'       => $_POST['num2'],
                              'num3'       => $_POST['num3']];

}


if(isset($_POST['selling_price_input'])) {

$_SESSION['selling_price'] = $_POST['selling_price'];
}      


?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    

<div class="form-group">
<label>Ingredient</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ingredient">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Price</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="num1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Qty Grams/Item</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="num2">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Recipe Qty Grams/Item</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="num3">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add_ingredient" value="Add Ingredient">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Selling Price</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="selling_price">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="selling_price_input" value="Update">
</div>
</form>


<!-----------------------------------------------------DISPLAYING------------->   

<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Ingredients</th>
<th>Item Price</th>
<th>Item Qty Grams/Unit</th>
<th>Recipe Qty Grams/Unit</th>
<th>Total Cost</th>

</tr>

</thead>
<tbody>


<?php

//calculation variables
//$num1 = $_SESSION['num1'];
//$num2 = $_SESSION['num2'];
//$num3 = $_SESSION['num3'];
//$ingredient = $_SESSION['ingredient'];
//$selling_price = $_SESSION['selling_price'];
////$sellnum = $_GET['sellnum'];
//$cost = $num1 / $num2 * $num3;
//$profit =  $selling_price - $cost ;
//$profper =  $profit / $selling_price * 100;  

    foreach ($_SESSION['ingredients'] as  $ingredient) {
    $ingredient = $ingredient['ingredient'];
    $num1       = $ingredient['num1'];
    $num2       = $ingredient['num2'];
    $num3       = $ingredient['num3'];

   echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$ingredient</td>";
echo "<td>$num1</td>";

echo "<td>$num2</td>";
echo "<td>$num3</td>";
//echo "<td>$cost</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}




?>
<!--
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Total Cost of Recipe</td>
<?php  echo "<td>$cost</td>"; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Selling price of each baked item</td>
<?php echo "<td>$selling_price</td>"; ?>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Profit per item</td>
<?php  echo "<td colspan='2'>$profit</td>"; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Profit Percentage</td>
<?php  echo "<td colspan='2'>$profper%</td>"; ?>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="6">Note: Your profit should never be more than 30% of the cost of you your product</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still writing over the initial tr, it also adds the ingredient in all td's